Getting an error for not finding "vxlapi.LIBMMCAN_DLL" while starting the application
I am developing an application that uses the Vector XL Driver Library via the vxlapi.dll. While running the application the error "Error while loading vxlapi.LIBMMCAN_DLL!" occurs and I have no idea what the problem is, the vxlapi.dll is present in the folder.
I use Qt Creator to develop a GUI-based Application accessing Vector Hardware. Something doesn't work out while loading the driver
